# AOP on methods implemented from interface Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I want to perform AOP on implemented method by an interface in a class.

Interface

```
package a.b.c;
public interface A
{
    void f1(Object ob);
}
```

Class Implementation

```
package a.b.c.d;
public class B implements A
{
    public void f1(Object ob){}
}
```

Advice

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyOwnAdvice
{
    @Before("execution(public void a.b.c.A+.f1(..))") 
    public void f2()
    {
        System.out.println("MyOwnAdvice.f2()");
    }
}
```

EDIT :
sorry for sharing half info.The actual implementation is like this :

```
package x.y;
public class NormalClass
{
    A a;

    void executeThis()
    {
        a.f1();
    }
}

<bean class="x.y.NormalClass" id="normalClass" >
    <property name="a" ref="b" />
</bean>
<bean class="a.b.c.d.B" id="b" />
```

Its not working for me.

Please update me if I am making any mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it should work if you instantiate the class yourself? Do you have load time weaving enabled?

Comment: You haven't enabled any aspect configs at all.

Comment: I have configured aspectj as <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> and its working with other methods.But not for this

Comment: Please add all that to your question.

Comment: I am so sorry but I cant share(I want to) my actual project code on stackoverflow and the problem of the code is its too big and too old in the terms of xml configurations.

Answer (score 0):

A objectA=new B(); is not dependency injection. Spring must create B and inject it, e.g.

```
...
@Autowired
A a;
...
```